# stack memory location

Tags: .net, cpu-architecture, cpu-registers, stack-memory

i know the heap memory is the part of ram.
but is stack memory  also the part of ram or stack memory is the part of cpu registers.
what is the default size for stack memory for .net4.0 applications

Answer (score 2):

The stack memory is a part of RAM. It is no different from the heap as far as the computer is concerned. It's only used in a different way.

Comment: then way accessing data from stack is fater then heap.

Comment: @slash shogdhe: It is typically cheaper to _allocate_ on the stack since it's just incrementing a pointer while more complex memory allocation schemes are typically used on the heap. Objects on the stack are also more likely to be available in the cache.

Comment: @slash: No, that's not true at all. There are multiple levels of cache on modern processors, and they cache *far* more than just registers.

Comment: @slash: Explain what? You made a claim which I believe to be untrue... there are several layers of caching in the CPU before you reach main memory.

Comment: no i dont mean to say u r wrong,, i am really very confuse with the memory location of stack.can u please send me the link that may help me

Answer (score 0):

Typically, program code space and heap memory are allocated from the bottom (starting at zero) of the memory space, on up.  Commonly, stacks start at the extreme top of the memory space and grow downward.  The initial stack size can be very small (one page), because when you outgrow it, a page fault will occur, and the OS can allocate more space, growing downward.

Incidentally, in 64-bit x86 processors, there is a big "gap" in the middle of the 64-bit address space, because the machine doesn't implement full 64-bit addressing.  See [this on wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X86-64#Virtual_address_space_details).

Answer (score 0):

> what is the default size for stack memory for .net4.0 applications

This is common for .Net and non-.net Windows applications. It is allocated per-thread. Each thread has its own stack. The typical amount is 1 MB. The default can be overridden:

- Per executable by controling exectuable headers. There's `/STACK` option in C++ compiler, so you can set that if you use C++/CLI to create .NET executables. Apparently, there's no option to control that in C# or F# though.
- Per thread. `System.Threading.Thread` has a constructor overload that takes stack reservation as one of the parameters.